# Flutter asset image displays the wrong image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have am `images` folder and inside it i have `table.png` and then i have a `main_menu` folder in which i have another `table.png` file.

- images

  - main_menu

    - table.png
    - //...other images here
  - table.png
  - //...other images here

When I do

```
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage("images/table.png"),
                        )
                      ),
```

it takes the `table.png` image from the `images/main_menu/` folder instead ... why is that?

Don't tell me it searches for the first place it finds the `table.png` file and just displays that. And in this case `table.png` under `main_menu` is the first one it finds and that's why it displays it. It's just a hunch but ... if it's true, then this is a bug, no ?

Cheers.

Comment: how did you declare the assets within the pubspec.yaml?

Comment: - images/table.png and  - images/main_menu/table.png

Comment: well, I did ... AssetImage("images/table.png"), That's exactly the problem, I can't see a problem, it should work. I need the images/table.png, but it seems it takes the one at the images/main_menu/table.png path instead.

Comment: you tried to clean up the project?

Comment: yup ... I currently solved it by just changing the name of one of the files, but I'd still wanna find out the issue...

Answer (score 2):

Try with this :

```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("./images/table.png"), 

     //instead of AssetImage("images/table.png") 

    )
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a different way to define images but i prefer this if picture in sub folder .
**This is my folder of** `assets->images`
I attaching Screenshot of folder below

[assets-->images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0o7N.png)

**And in `pubspec.yaml` i define like this**

[pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDAcA.png)

hope it will works :D

**And in class use like this**

```
title: Image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/xyz.png'),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference this part: [Flutter Docs: Specifying assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets)

> Note: Only files located directly in the directory are included unless there are files with the same name inside a subdirectory (see [Asset Variants](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-variants)). To add files located in subdirectories, create an entry per directory.